# how to installing fbprophet module

Tags: python, installation, pip, facebook-prophet

I type some code about forecasting and predicting price of bitcoin.
Before installing fbprophet,
it need to install pystan first.

but i failed to build pystan WHEN I open cmd and type "pip install pystan"

could someone give me a hand?

below is my code:

```python
import pandas as pd

from fbprophet import Prophet

df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\downloads\BTC-USD.csv')
df = df[["Date", "Close"]]
df.columns = ["ds", "y"]
print(df)

prophet = Prophet()
prophet.fit(df)

future = prophet.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
print(future)

forecast = prophet.predict(future)
forecast[["ds", "yhat", "yhat_lower", "yhat_upper"]].tail(200)

from fbprophet.plot import plot
prophet.plot(forecast, figsize=(20, 10))
```

below is my terminal result:

```
PS D:\python> python 211030.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\211030.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fbprophet import Prophet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'
```

Comment: If you tell us what you got when installing with pip, it will be easier to give you an answer ;)

Comment: ok, i have put the sceenshot(the screenshot about pip install fbprophet)，thankyou

Comment: Actually, pasting the output as code blocks would be best :)

Comment: Oh it seems like you have a _really big_ output! Maybe you can post the message on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) (or sth similar), and just share the link in your question. But output screenshots are not recommended.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, after i replace pip with anaconda, it worked.

Comment: Well, if you consider you found the answer, you can post your own answer, and mark it as your selected answer.